# How to target a class dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am working on the demo below. Why am I not able to add the `.red` to the `.ew-num` dynamically?

```js
$(".ew-increaser").on("click", function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
    $(this).parent().prev(".ew-num").addClass('red');
    $(this).parent().find(".ew-num").addClass('red');
    $(this).parent().prev("ew-num").addClass('red');
    $(this).parent().find("ew-num").addClass('red');
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:30px;
}
.red{
    background:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ew-decreaser">Left</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ew-num">Middle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ew-increaser">Right</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).parent()` refers to direct parent `<div class="btn-group" role="group">`, and it doesn't contain `.ew-num`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target child of `parent()`'s `prev()`sibling

```js
$(".ew-increaser").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().prev().children(".ew-num").addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ew-decreaser">Left</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ew-num">Middle</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ew-increaser">Right</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-You should use the `children()` to get parent `div` child elements

```js
$(".ew-increaser").on("click", function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
    $(this).parent().prev().children(".ew-num").addClass('red');
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:30px;
}
.red{
    background:red!important;;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ew-decreaser">Left</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ew-num">Middle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ew-increaser">Right</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```